# JS: Filter array of objects by max value per category

Tags: javascript, arrays

What is most efficient / elegant way to achieve sql-like filtering effect. I want to filter them and get only that objects which are max value in some group.

This is my code, it works but probably it's not best way:

```
uniqueValues = (arr) => [...new Set(arr)];
getMaxTimeOf = (arr) => Math.max(...arr.map(o => o.timeStamp), 0);
selectorName = (name) => (obj) => obj.name === name;
selectorTime = (time) => (obj) => obj.timeStamp === time;
getGroup = (obj, selector) => obj.filter(selector)

onlyLastChangedFrom = (history) => {
const uniqueNames = uniqueValues(history.map(o => o.name))
let filtered = []
 uniqueNames.forEach(name => {
  const group = getGroup(history, selectorName(name))
  const groupLastTime = getMaxTimeOf(group)
  const lastChange = getGroup(group, selectorTime(groupLastTime))
  filtered.push(lastChange[0])
 });
 return filtered
}   
onlyLastChangedFrom(history)
```

```
    // Input:
    [ { name: 'bathroom',
        value: 54,
        timeStamp: 1562318089713 },
      { name: 'bathroom',
        value: 55,
        timeStamp: 1562318090807 },
      { name: 'bedroom',
        value: 48,
        timeStamp: 1562318092084 },
      { name: 'bedroom',
        value: 49,
        timeStamp: 1562318092223 },
      { name: 'room',
        value: 41,
        timeStamp: 1562318093467 } ]

    // Output:
    [ { name: 'bathroom',
        value: 55,
        timeStamp: 1562318090807 },
      { name: 'bedroom',
        value: 49,
        timeStamp: 1562318092223 },
      { name: 'room',
        value: 41,
        timeStamp: 1562318093467 } ]
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) the array to an object, using the `name` property as the key. For each item, check if the item that exists in the accumulator has a higher value than the current item, and if not replace it with the current item. Convert back to an array with [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values):

```js
const arr = [{"name":"bathroom","value":54,"timeStamp":1562318089713},{"name":"bathroom","value":55,"timeStamp":1562318090807},{"name":"bedroom","value":48,"timeStamp":1562318092084},{"name":"bedroom","value":49,"timeStamp":1562318092223},{"name":"room","value":41,"timeStamp":1562318093467}]

const result = Object.values(arr.reduce((r, o) => {
  r[o.name] = (r[o.name] && r[o.name].value > o.value) ? r[o.name] : o

  return r
}, {}))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: No. We need to assign to `r[o.name]` the result of the ternary `r[o.name] && r[o.name].value > o.value ? r[o.name] : o`.

Comment: I see then "r[o.name] = r[o.name] && r[o.name].value > o.value ? r[o.name] : o" is "r[o.name] = (r[o.name] && r[o.name].value > o.value) ? r[o.name] : o"

Answer (score 2):

I love to use [lodash](https://lodash.com/) for stuff like this. It's very functional and therefore very clear and straightforward.

Take a look at the following code:

```js
const DATA = [
  {
    name: "bathroom",
    value: 54,
    timeStamp: 1562318089713
  },
  {
    name: "bathroom",
    value: 55,
    timeStamp: 1562318090807
  },
  {
    name: "bedroom",
    value: 48,
    timeStamp: 1562318092084
  },
  {
    name: "bedroom",
    value: 49,
    timeStamp: 1562318092223
  },
  {
    name: "room",
    value: 41,
    timeStamp: 1562318093467
  }
];

let max = _
  .chain(DATA)
  .groupBy('name')
  .sortBy('value')
  .map(o => _(o).reverse().first())
  .flatten()
  .value();

console.log(max); // returns [{"name":"bathroom","value":55,"timeStamp":1562318090807},{"name":"bedroom","value":49,"timeStamp":1562318092223},{"name":"room","value":41,"timeStamp":1562318093467}]
```

Comment: Chain lodash function is not friendly with lodash es (when you want use treeshaking)
To use chain function with es import see that answer on github https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/3298#issuecomment-341685354

Answer (score 2):

> What is most efficient / elegant way to achieve sql-like filtering effect.

You could take functions for every step and pipe all functions for a single result.

For example in SQL, you would have the following query:

```
SELECT name, value, MAX(timeStamp) 
FROM data 
GROUP BY name;
```

With an SQL like approach, you could group first and take the max object out of the result sets.

```
result = pipe(
    groupBy('name'),
    select(max('timeStamp'))
)(data);
```

```js
const
    pipe = (...functions) => input => functions.reduce((acc, fn) => fn(acc), input),
    groupBy = key => array => array.reduce((r, o) => {
        var temp = r.find(([p]) => o[key] === p[key])
        if (temp) temp.push(o);
        else r.push([o]);
        return r;
    }, []),
    max = key => array => array.reduce((a, b) => a[key] > b[key] ? a : b),
    select = fn => array => array.map(fn);


var data = [{ name: 'bathroom', value: 54, timeStamp: 1562318089713 }, { name: 'bathroom', value: 55, timeStamp: 1562318090807 }, { name: 'bedroom', value: 48, timeStamp: 1562318092084 }, { name: 'bedroom', value: 49, timeStamp: 1562318092223 }, { name: 'room', value: 41, timeStamp: 1562318093467 }],
    result = pipe(
        groupBy('name'),
        select(max('timeStamp'))
    )(data);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another reduce alternative :

```js
var arr = [{"name":"bathroom","value":54,"timeStamp":1562318089713},{"name":"bathroom","value":55,"timeStamp":1562318090807},{"name":"bedroom","value":48,"timeStamp":1562318092084},{"name":"bedroom","value":49,"timeStamp":1562318092223},{"name":"room","value":41,"timeStamp":1562318093467}];

var obj = arr.reduce((r, o) => (o.value < (r[o.name] || {}).value || (r[o.name] = o), r), {});

console.log( Object.values(obj) );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) by keeping an accumulated object which keeps the max group currently found and then use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to get an array of those objects (instead of an key-value pair object relationship).

See example below:

```js
const arr=[{name:"bathroom",value:54,timeStamp:1562318089713},{name:"bathroom",value:55,timeStamp:1562318090807},{name:"bedroom",value:48,timeStamp:1562318092084},{name:"bedroom",value:49,timeStamp:1562318092223},{name:"room",value:41,timeStamp:1562318093467}];

const res = Object.values(arr.reduce((acc, o) => {
  acc[o.name] = acc[o.name] || o;
  if (o.value > acc[o.name].value)
    acc[o.name] = o;
  return acc;
}, {}));

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing this in stages.

1. get a set of names
2. create a sorted array in descending order
3. then just map using find to get the first one

Below is an example.

```js
const input = [{"name":"bathroom","value":54,"timeStamp":1562318089713},{"name":"bathroom","value":55,"timeStamp":1562318090807},{"name":"bedroom","value":48,"timeStamp":1562318092084},{"name":"bedroom","value":49,"timeStamp":1562318092223},{"name":"room","value":41,"timeStamp":1562318093467}];

const output = [...new Set(input.map(m => m.name))].
  map(m => [...input].sort(
    (a,b) => b.value - a.value).
    find(x => m === x.name));
  
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `map()` and  `foreach()` to get desired output

```
const arr=[{name:"bathroom",value:54,timeStamp:1562318089713}, 
    {name:"bathroom",value:55,timeStamp:1562318090807}, 
    {name:"bedroom",value:48,timeStamp:1562318092084}, 
    {name:"bedroom",value:49,timeStamp:1562318092223}, 
    {name:"room",value:41,timeStamp:1562318093467}];

let res = new Map();
arr.forEach((obj) => {
    let values = res.get(obj.name);
    if(!(values && values.value > obj.value)){ 
        res.set(obj.name, obj) 
    }
})
console.log(res);
console.log([...res])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sort and filter methods

```js
const arr = [{"name":"bathroom","value":54,"timeStamp":1562318089713},{"name":"bathroom","value":55,"timeStamp":1562318090807},{"name":"bedroom","value":48,"timeStamp":1562318092084},{"name":"bedroom","value":49,"timeStamp":1562318092223},{"name":"room","value":41,"timeStamp":1562318093467}]
arr.sort(function (a, b) {
    return b.value - a.value;
}).filter((v, i, a) => a.findIndex((v2) => v2.name === v.name) === i);

console.log(arr);
```