# Remove duplicate objects in JSON array with jq based on specific criteria

Tags: json, unique, jq

I have the following data where I want entire objects removed based on duplicate values of the `"run"` key, while keeping the object with the largest `"startTime"` number:

```
{
  "data": {
    "results": [
      {
        "event": {
          "biking": {
            "startTime": 12,
            "id": "a",
            "run": "x"
          }
        },
        "displayName": "Alex"
      },
      {
        "event": {
          "biking": {
            "startTime": 10,
            "id": "b",
            "run": "x"
          }
        },
        "displayName": "Adam"
      },
      {
        "event": {
          "biking": {
            "startTime": 11,
            "id": "c",
            "run": "y"
          }
        },
        "displayName": "Aaron"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I've been trying to finagle `unique` with `jq` but can't quite get what I want.  My intended result is this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "results": [
      {
        "event": {
          "biking": {
            "startTime": 12,
            "id": "a",
            "run": "x"
          }
        },
        "displayName": "Alex"
      },
      {
        "event": {
          "biking": {
            "startTime": 11,
            "id": "c",
            "run": "y"
          }
        },
        "displayName": "Aaron"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I was trying to use `unique` because I want to keep only 1 of each `"run":` ids where in a larger list I might have three `x`, two `y`, and four `z`.  I'd want to keep one `x`, `y`, and `z` in this case based on the largest `"startTime"`.

Comment: What have you tried so far - Show us your attempt to code this please.

Comment: use Array `filter` function

Comment: The question has been tagged with both the jq and jquery tags, but these have almost nothing to do with each other.  If you want a jQuery solution, please change the title; otherwise, please remove the jquery tag. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up!  jquery tag removed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a straightforward jq solution:

```
.data.results |=
  (group_by(.event.biking.run)
   | map(max_by(.event.biking.startTime)))
```

It uses `group_by` to group by "run", and then `max_by` to select the desired event.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

- Here's how it can be done using reducer.

```js
const input = {
  "data": {
    "results": [{
        "event": {
          "biking": {
            "startTime": 12,
            "id": "a",
            "run": "x"
          }
        },
        "displayName": "Alex"
      },
      {
        "event": {
          "biking": {
            "startTime": 10,
            "id": "b",
            "run": "x"
          }
        },
        "displayName": "Adam"
      },
      {
        "event": {
          "biking": {
            "startTime": 11,
            "id": "c",
            "run": "y"
          }
        },
        "displayName": "Aaron"
      }
    ]
  }
};
const output = {
  data: {}
};
output.data.results = Object.values(input.data.results.reduce((r, o) => {
  r[o.event.biking.run] =
    (r[o.event.biking.run] &&
      r[o.event.biking.run].event.biking.startTime > o.event.biking.startTime) ? r[o.event.biking.run] : o
  return r
}, {}));
console.log(output);
```

- Credits -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/56901839/8057127

Answer (score 0):

This would work

```
const result = [
  ...new Map(
    obj.data.results.map((item) => [item["event"]["biking"]["run"], item])
  ).values()
];
```

[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/white-butterfly-eml2r?file=/src/App.js)

This is based on [helprjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/helprjs) removeDuplicates.